# Finding a triangle parallel to another triangle

Tags: geometry

I have three points $A,B,C$ on the surface of a sphere and a triangle (inside the sphere) between them. I would like to find a similar triangle parallel to $ABC$ which is coplanar to a point $D$ inside the sphere, with its vertices $A',B',C'$ also being on the surface.

Basically, I would like to take the triangle $ABC$ and move the vertices along the surface of the sphere, stretching/shrinking the triangle accordingly, until it reaches point $D$.

How can this be done?

Comment: What does parallel mean? That there is an isometry of the sphere mapping one triangle to the other?

Comment: (Either way, the use of the term parallel is a little perverse, given that there are no parallel lines on the sphere.)

Comment: @Travis The triangle $A'B'C'$ should lie on plane parallel to the plane containing triangle $ABC$. I think I was a bit unclear as the triangle is not on the surface of the sphere, only the vertices are. I will clarify.

Comment: @Travis: "Inside the sphere" does not mean "*on* the sphere".

Comment: Are you sure the triangle you're looking for exists? Specifically, I'm not convinced you can get a similar triangle that is also parallel and has vertices lying on the sphere.

Comment: @JakobHansen The triangle is inside the ball. Imagine a cross-section of the ball containing the triangle $ABC$: I want the cross-section through $A'B'C'$ to look identical, but scaled accordingly. Therefore the triangle should always exist.

Comment: Ok, you're right. But then that makes finding the triangle easy. First find the plane going through D that is parallel to ABC. Then pick three points on the cross section of the sphere so that the angles between the lines they define are the same as the angles of ABC.

Comment: I guess you will have to consider the plane containing the first triangle and look at the perpendicular line from D to this plane. This gives you the normal line to the plane you want and since you have a point on the plane you can find its equation. Then just choose three points appropriately on the new plane that lie on the sphere and you are done.

Comment: @AlexM. "Inside the sphere" was added to the statement of the question in response to my earlier comments.

Comment: @JakobHansen  How do I make sure that $A'B'C'$ isn't rotated with respect to $ABC$? That is, you can imagine moving the triangle along the sphere without rotating it.

Comment: @Rise Similarly to my comment above, how do I make sure that the three points on the plane are chosen appropriately and the triangle is not rotated with respect to $ABC$?

Comment: Well intuitively, the sphere has meridians (longitude they're called in geography). You have to take the three meridians passing through A B and C and see where the intersect the new plane. These meridians are basically the smallest curves (geodesics) on the surface of the sphere from the North Pole to the south pole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any triangle ABC, there exists a triangle A'B'C' that is similar to ABC, lies in a plane parallel to ABC and touches the surface of the sphere.  To construct this triangle, find the circumcenter of ABC.  The vector from the circumcenter through the center of the sphere will go through the circumcenter of A'B'C'

So, you can project along this vector to the appropriate plane.  Apply a dilation / compression until the triangle touches the surface of the sphere.  However, there is a possibility that D is not currently in this triangle.  However, you can now rotate this triangle about the circumcenter until the point D is in the interior of the triangle.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to formulate "apply a dilation / compression until the triangle touches the surface of the sphere" in more specific terms? How could I get the points that correspond to a dilated/compressed triangle on the surface?

Comment: you find distance from the center of the sphere to the plane containing ABC.  The radius of the circle created by the intersection of the plane and the sphere is a circle of radius $\sqrt{R^2 - d^2}$.  Then you find the distance to the plane containing D, and find the radius of the circle in that plane, and the ratio of the two is your compression factor.